# Render View with title in twig template?

Tags: views, 8, theming

Is there a version of drupal_view (or alternative) that will render a view with the title? It's a pain to hardcode titles or preprocess individual views just to get a title to render that is already configured per display from the views interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should develop a custom twig extension for that.
I developed a simple module [twig_views](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_views) for that purpose check it out.

Example of use:

```
 {{ render_view('view_machine_name', 'display_name') }}
```

if you use `8.2.6` drupal version, and [twig_xdebug](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_xdebug) Module 
you may have some error like:

> The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
>   Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\LogicException: Service 'twig_xdebug' for consumer 'twig' does not implement Twig_ExtensionInterface.

Those steps in [this comment](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_xdebug/issues/2852208#comment-12156020) will solve your problem.

Comment: Haven't gotten to test it yet but this looks like it'll work! Really don't understand why this isn't built into Views by default

Comment: I don't know either, when i saw your question, before i start developing, i searched for something build in, i didn't find nothing, and it's same to me important. i have tried with 'views_embed_view' but no luck to get the title also.